# Linear Algebra Transformation Matrix - From a point to a different point by multiplying by a matrix?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, transformation, linear-algebra

I'm only familiar with linear algebra, but I'm trying to make a crosshair on a graphics app I am working on.

```
I have a point: (x,y,z)
```

And I'm trying to get it to the point:

```
(2/(x+y),(5y+z)/(2x+2y),3)
```

I've been reading and it can be done by multiplying my point by a 'transformation matrix' to get my desired point. But I'm not sure how to do this.

Does anyone know if there's a step by step on how to get it to that coordinates? If I could see a end result, I could try and reverse it.

Comment: That doesn't seem linear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to add a homogeneous coordinate *w*;
Then your equations are of form

[x,y,z,w=1] * [4x4] matrix = [WX,WY,WZ,W],
where dividing by W (which should be (x+y)) you can maybe reach the expected result...

So, you got to find a matrix M, which represents the following equations:

```
WX = 2, 
WY = 2.5y+0.5z, 
WZ = 3x+3y, 
W  = x+y
```

Comment: As additional side note: in openGL shader e.g. you will end up passing the vector gl_Position = [xw,xy,xz,w] = Matrix*vec4(x,y,z,1.0) in vertex shader and the fixed (invisible) part of the rendering pipeline does the interpolation, clipping and ultimately the division.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that directly, because only linear transformations (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) can be represented by a matrix, and your transformation is not linear. What you can do is to rewrite your transformation as follows:

```
(x,y,z,w)->( 2w , 5y/2+z/2 , 3x+3y )
```

which is linear now, and its respective transformation is given by:

```
T(x,y,z,w)=[0  0  0  2; 0  5/2  1/2  0; 3  3  0  0]*(x,y,z,w)
```

where the matrix is given by the numbers between the []'s and each row is separated by a ';'. As you can see, you now have a linear transformation that does not give the point that you need, but if you evaluate your transformation in w=1, and also divide each entry in the resulting vector by (x+y), then you have the result that you want to achieve. I mean,

```
(2/(x+y),(5y+z)/(2x+2y),3) = 
[1/(x+y)]*[0  0  0  2; 0  5/2  1/2  0; 3  3  0  0]*(x,y,z,w=1)
```

I hope this is useful for you.

Comment: The divisor (x+1) is typically also calculated by the same matrix

Comment: Not only linear transformations can be represented by matrices. Other transformations, like affine or projective transformations, can also be described by matrices, coordinate systems other than the Cartesian coordinate system (e.g. homogeneous coordinate system) are used in these cases though.

Comment: I think you can with nonlinear transformations, but you maybe have to do something tricky to get the transformation to something linear. Because matrices are linear transformations, how can be possible that something linear is at the same time nonlinear?